# User control from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Can we use ".ascx" in ".vb" page ?

As you know, we can use .ascx such as  in ".aspx". But I wonder that how can use it from ".vb"?

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: There is a long structure which is started <div> and finished </div> approximately 100 lines. I will control id if id = 101 then "that code" will come here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you should be able to add ascx user controls to a VB page -

```
Dim myControl As Control = CType(Page.LoadControl("UC1.ascx"), Control) 
Panel1.Controls.Add(myControl)
```

Comment: without panel, cannot we use?

Comment: @ToUpper: A UserControl's purpose is to be on an aspx page (or nested in other Controls/UserControls), so yes, you should add it to the page or to controls that are on a page. But you are not forced to do so, you can load it into memory and call it's functions without adding it to the page's control-collection. What you need is the first line of jpr101's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can load `UserControl` dynamically like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, evtArgs As EventArgs)
    Dim loadedControl = LoadControl("~/path/to/your/ascx/file")
    loadedControl.ID = "myLoadedControl"
    anyPanel.Controls.Add(loadedControl)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The .ascx (web control) would usually have other web controls within it (such as asp:TextBox, etc.).  You can access these from the .ascx.vb file (a partial class, automatically created by Visual Studio).  If you want to expose these controls and/or their properties to the .aspx file you've placed your .ascx web control in, you'll need to create public properties for them.

For example: If your .ascx has an asp:TextBox called "txtUserId", and you want to be able to get/set the Text property of this textbox from the .aspx page, you could add the following:

```
Public Property UserIdText As String
    Get
        Return Me.txtUserID.Text
    End Get
    Set (value As String)
        Me.txtUserId.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```